How to change implementation service in runtime
I am wondering is it possible in runtime to change implementation of service. Let's say I have:
public interface Service {} from Core project
public class ImplA : Service {} from LibraryA.dll 
public class ImplB : Service {} from LibraryB.dll

And is it possible to register only Service in DI and in runtime changing the implementation of service from LibraryA or LibraryB? I have the method where I register all services from library but I don't know is it possible to change library in runtime.
This is the code where I register services:
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");                })
            ;
        
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<App>();

        RegisterServices(builder.Services);

        var app = builder.Build();

        return app;
    }

    public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string dllFileName = "LibraryA.dll";
        var mobileAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "Application.Libraries.LibraryA.dll";
        var destinationPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, dllFileName);

        using (Stream? resourceStream = mobileAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            if (resourceStream == null) return;
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                resourceStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            var dllPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, dllFileName);
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
            var serviceTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Any());

            foreach (var implementationType in serviceTypes)
            {
                var interfaceType = implementationType.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault();
                if (interfaceType != null)
                {
                    var descriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == interfaceType);
                    if (descriptor != null)
                    {
                        services.Remove(descriptor);
                    }

                    services.AddSingleton(interfaceType, implementationType);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   

And it works as I expect but the LibraryA.dll is hardcoded in RegisterServices method. I want to get solution where I would flexible change libraries in runtime. The libraires are embedded resources.

Need research but I heard AutoFAC is able to handle libraries linking at runtime

Not sure about the whole architecture of the project, but you can register different implementations in for one interface with Keys, this is in .NET, not sure about MAUI. It worth to try it.
Docs
Depending on that key you can dynamically invoke different implementations

@mihkov that should work for MAUI too

Resolve manually to ImplA or ImplB. Do not implement factory.

After the service provider is built, the registrations are fixed and can't be changed. While some DI Containers allow you to change registrations later on, this practice is discourages, because it is very easy to cause all kind of hard to track and hard to solve side effects.
As a simple example of how changing the registration might not lead to the desired effect, assume that ImplA gets injected into a singleton, let's call it Consumer. Even if you swap implementations to ImplB later on, that wouldn't change the fact that Consumer is already built and already references ImplA. Swapping out ImplA with ImplBinside the container will not automatically swap the reference helt byConsumer`.
This is a relatively simple example, but problems can arise even in situations where ImplA is never injected into singletons as well. This is why you should strive for alternatives.
Instead of trying to swap registrations inside the container, prefer composing the exact object graph of registrations up front without the need to change that structure later on. Of course you still want a different implementation to be called later on, but you can do this using patterns such as Proxy, Adapter, and Composite.
For instance, you can create the following Service implementation:
public class SwitchInfo
{
    public bool UseA { get; set; }
}

public class SwitchableService : Service
{
    public SwitchableService(SwitchInfo info, ImplA a, ImplB b) ...

    public void DoSomething() => this.GetImplementation().DoSomething();

    private Service GetImplementation() => this.info.UseA ? this.a : this.b;
}

This can be registered as follows:
var info = SwitchInfo { UseA = true };

services.AddSingleton(info);
services.AddTransient<SwitchableService>();
services.AddTransient<ImplA>();
services.AddTransient<ImplB>();

services.AddTransient<Service>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<SwitchableService>());

With this registration, every time an Service is injected into a consumer, it will get the following object graph:
new SwitchableService(
    info,
    new ImplA(...),
    new ImplB(...));

Whenever the consumer calls that dependency, SwitchableService can decide whether it should call A or B. Using the info variable (of type SwitchInfo) you can now at any time switch from A to B:
info.UseA = false;

While the code above will likely not exactly work for your specific case, as you're doing dynamic assembly loading, it will still -hopefully- give you a direction for a solution.
In your case, you could load the Service implementation of assembly one and the Service implementation of assembly two and register them, e.g.:
var info = SwitchInfo { UseA = true };

Type a = LoadServiceImplFromAssembly("AssemblyA");
Type b = LoadServiceImplFromAssembly("AssemblyB");

services.AddTransient(a);
services.AddTransient(b);

services.AddTransient<Service>(sp => SwitchableService(
    info,
    (Service)sp.GetRequiredService(a),
    (Service)sp.GetRequiredService(b)));

In this case, the constructor of SwitchableService will have to change, as you don't know the types up front:
public SwitchableService(SwitchInfo info, Service a, Service b) ...


If you click twice on the tooltip to see other overloads for adding services, you will see something that takes "ImplementationFactory" as parameter. It does exactly what it promises to do - it is a factory for providing the correct implementation at runtime.
(Most of the answers you will see, make use of exactly this way of calling the method, all of them are correct, working, textbook answers.)
It can be as simple to use as x?sp.get(a):sp.get(b), and I found it to be very useful for configuring the backend to behave differently, depending on the requirement of the clients.
However.
The first thing you will ask "Ok, now how to pass parameter from the business logic".
Suddenly it is not that simple.
(If you come from writing android native apps, and you want something like "@AssistedInject", you will be surprised of the amount of extra code you have to write, to get near this functionality.)
Second thing you will ask "Why is not the behavior actually changing".
Well, you will see that once reference "provided", nothing will go and check your references, and replace them with new references at runtime.
If we add that we have "platform specific services" implementations (besides the regular #if...), and some very specific cases for occasionally "reconstructing" singletons (HttpClients are not disposed, so you neither can use new every time, neither can "repair" old one. At least this was the case like a year ago).
At the end you will see that resolving manually your service, is not that bad.
Get your service provider in your ViewModel, check your condition, then get the required service.
Save yourself some pain. You will always have the right implementation exactly when you need to call the code.
